# How do I get the data from datasets & I view on the DataGridView with a different layout formats

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

Can you help my problem?

> I have 2 tables : product (as parent) and sales (as a child).
>
> product table consists of:
> product_id | product_name | product_price |
> 1 | book | $5 |
>
> sales table consist of:
> transaction_id | product_id | quantity | total_price |
> A001 | 1 | 10 | $50 |

1. product_id  at the product table is pK for product table.
2. transaction_id  at the sales table is pK for sales table .
3. product_id  at the sales table as fK, which a reference to the product_id of product table

All my tables are stored in the dataset. How do I get the data from these datasets can I view on the DataGridView with a different layout formats, as follows.

> transaction_id | product_name | product_price | quantity | total_price |
> A001 | book | $5 | 10 | $50 |

Thanks & Best Regards,

YDA

Comment: Product to Sales is a one-to-many relationship?  You want the tables joined into one DataGridView, or two DataGridViews in a Master-Detail format?

Comment: I want the two tables joined into one DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you write your query to populate your dataset in the format you want?  If so, I think you can just databind the resulting datatable to the DataGridView and get what you want.  So your query would be something like:

```
"SELECT transaction_id, product_name, product_price, quantity, total_price, A001, book, $5, 10, $50 from product join sales on product.productid = sales.productid"
```

Of course, you would replace $5 and so on with the actual column names.  Use that query to populate a dataset, then on your form.

```
DataGridView.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("MyJoinedDataTable")
```

Where "MyJoinedDataTable" is the name of the table that you populated in the dataset.

Comment: I can display data from two data tables, with the join. If I want both the data tables display in the form of master-detail in single DataGridView, is it possible? This relates to the Nested DataGridView or Host DataGridView in DataGridView. Thanks.

Comment: I refer to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx), but still confused.. (:

Comment: @yudha, I don't believe you can do that with one DataGridView out of the box.  I normally do it with two DataGridViews.  There are probably third party grids that you can purchase that would have that functionality, for instance a "+" sign beside each Parent item that would expand the children below it.  The link you are looking at is for making a custom DataGridViewColumn.  I'm not sure how you would use that in your scenario to do what you want.